# My Swagger shows error before I create new controller for referencing other controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-7.0

I created a new controller so that I can put a function in it and use it in all controllers, and all controllers inherit from this controller, but I get an error.

My Swagger UI shows this error :

> Fetch error
> Internal Server Error https://localhost:7032/swagger/v1/swagger.json

Swager log have :
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

`BaseController` :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace TodoList.Api.Controllers
{
    public class BaseController : ControllerBase
    {
       public string GetId()
        {
            if (HttpContext.User.Identity is ClaimsIdentity identity)
            {
                if (identity != null)
                {
                    var IdUser = identity?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.SerialNumber).Value;
                    return IdUser!;
                }
            }

            return null!;
        }
    }
}
```

Other controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using TodoList.Api.DbContextFolder;
using TodoList.Api.Entity;
using TodoList.Api.Model;

namespace TodoList.Api.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/TaskManage")]
    [Authorize]
    public class TaskController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly TaskDbContext taskDbContext;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
                    
        public TaskController(TaskDbContext taskDbContext,IMapper mapper)
        {
            this.taskDbContext = taskDbContext;
            this._mapper = mapper;
        }

        // GET: api/values
        [HttpGet("All")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<ICollection< TaskEntity>>> GetAllTask()
        { 
            var result = await taskDbContext.TaskDb.ToListAsync();

            if (HttpContext.User.Identity is ClaimsIdentity identity)
            {
                var IdUser = identity?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.SerialNumber).Value;
            }

            return Ok(result);
        }

        // GET api/id
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<TaskEntity>> GetBuyId(int id)
        {
            var result = await taskDbContext.TaskDb.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == id);

            if (result == null)
            {
                return NotFound(result);
            }

            return Ok(result);
        }

        // POST api/Create
        [HttpPost("Create")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<TaskEntity>> CreateToDo(TaskSendDTO T)
        {
            if (T != null)
            {
                var IdUser = GetId();
                //var IdUser = User.Claims.First(x => x.Type == "Id").Value;
                
                var DataMapper = _mapper.Map<TaskEntity>(T);

                DataMapper.createById = Convert.ToInt32(IdUser);

                //DataMapper.createBy = taskDbContext.UsersAccounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == Convert.ToInt32(IdUser));

                await taskDbContext.TaskDb.AddAsync(DataMapper);

                taskDbContext.SaveChanges();

                return Ok(DataMapper);
            }

            return BadRequest("Something went wrong");
        }

        // PUT api/NameUpdate/id
        [HttpPut("NameUpdate/{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<TaskUpdateTitle>> UpdateNameToDo(int id,string value)
        {
            var FindId = taskDbContext.TaskDb.Find(id);

            if (FindId == null)
            {
                return NotFound(FindId);
            }

            var DataNew = await taskDbContext.TaskDb.Select(e =>  e.Title).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            FindId.Title = value;

            if (FindId.Title is not null)
            {
                //taskDbContext.Update(FindId);
                taskDbContext.SaveChanges();
                return Ok(FindId.Title);
            }

            return NotFound();
        }

        //put api/IsDoneUpdate/Id
        [HttpPut("IsDoneUpdate")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<TaskUpdateIsDoneDTO>> UpdateIsDone(int[] ids)
        {
            var tasks  = await
                taskDbContext
                .TaskDb
                .Where(t=> ids.Contains(t.Id)).ToListAsync();

            if (ids.Length != tasks.Count)
            {
                return NotFound(tasks);
            }
            
            foreach (var task in tasks)
            {
                task.IsDone = true;
            }

            taskDbContext.SaveChanges();

            return Ok();
        }

        //DELETE api/TaskId
        [HttpDelete("{TaskId}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<TaskEntity>> DeleteBuyId(int TaskId)
        {
            var result = await taskDbContext.TaskDb.FindAsync(TaskId);

            if (result == null)
            {
                return NotFound(result);
            }

            taskDbContext.Remove(result);
            taskDbContext.SaveChanges();

            return NoContent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to your error description it Indicates a general server-side issue, preventing Swagger from generating the swagger.json.
As per the scenario error occurs after introducing the BaseController, would you temporarily comment out or remove the BaseController and inheritance.
See if Swagger works without it. If it does, focus on the BaseController implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid showing the GetId method in the API list and prevent conflicts with other methods that have the same type and name in your controllers, you just need to add the **[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]** attribute above your GetId method in the base controller:

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public string GetId()
{
....
}
```